# Esper HA V/s Esper + Storm

Tags: apache-storm, esper

I was using open source version of Esper to perform some complex event processing. I am using combination of Esper + Storm so that i can write my CEP logic in Storm bolt which is distributed across network.

Esper also provides its HA version which is high availability. My Questions is that what are the advantages using Esper HA instead of using Esper (Open source) + Storm combination.

Answer (score 0):

EsperHA+Storm gives the same as Esper+Storm with the addition of persistence of the Esper statement state. Upon failover or rebalancing of Storm workers the state is not lost.